# Get content from page requiring authorization

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, file-get-contents, roblox

I have a **successful script** in Node.js which manages to get content from a page which requires authorization, by mimicking the login process.

I now need to get content from the webpage for a slightly different purpose using PHP and have attempted to "convert" the script from Javascript to PHP, however, it doesn't work.

Could someone help me switch the code from Javascript to PHP or let me know what's wrong with my current code?

**Javascript Node.js Authorization**

```
var request = require("request");
var j = request.jar();
var cookie = request.cookie('entercookie');

j.setCookie(cookie, 'http://www.example.com');
var request = request.defaults({jar: j});

request.post('https://www.example.com/login', {username: 'username', password: 'password'}, function(err, res, body) {
    makeRequest(100);
});
```

**PHP Authorization**

```
$homepage = 'http://example.com';

$postData = http_build_query(
    array(
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password'
    )
);
$cookie = 'cookie';

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
                      Cookie: '.$cookie,
        'content' => $postData
    )
));
$data = file_get_contents($homepage, false, $context);

echo $data;
```

As you can see, I've set the username, password and cookie for the page (as I did in the Node.js scrpt), however the specified error is occurring.

I would like to add that I'm open to using `cURL` if it's a better solution.

Comment: Maybe I'm remembering my specs wrong, but in HTTP Basic authorization, cookies aren't sent along, so there wouldn't be concatenation in base64 of the `:$cookie`

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi Would using `cURL` be a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that on your javascript code you are doing a POST request with the username and password.

On your PHP code you are doing a GET request with basic authentication, change your php code to something like this:

```
$homepage = 'http://authorizationpage.com';

$postData = http_build_query(
    array(
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password'
    )
);
$cookie = 'cookie';

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
                      Cookie: '.$cookie,
        'content' => $postData
    )
));
$data = file_get_contents($homepage, false, $context);

echo $data;
```

Comment: Hmmm... I seem to get the error `Notice: file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and                                `Warning: file_get_contents(http://authorizationpage.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Token Validation Failed`

Comment: Would it be easier if I gave you the URL to the page which requires authorization?

Comment: @bobjomes I added the content to the header to remove the notice, as for the warning it seems that your website requests a token and it's giving you a 403

Comment: I adjusted the code (using your updated answer) and the `Notice` has now disappeared, but the other `Warning` is still there. Would there be a reason why it works in Node.js but not in PHP?

Comment: @bobjomes my guess would be something wrong with the cookie, can you show it?

Comment: Not really... people can use it to login to your account. I'm using the same cookie in both the scripts (Node.js and PHP) so I'm not sure that's the problem

Comment: I'm just thinking, there's no login form on the page defined in `$homepage`.. users have to log in on a different page. Is there a way I can specify which URL to log into?

Comment: @bobjomes No login form? you are misunderstanding all both php and javascript code do a http request to a website, they **don't** go to the website and fill the form with the username and password for you.

Comment: What do you recommend I do?

Comment: @bobjomes I don't know, you need to give more information or at least talk to someone close to you and show your code so they can help you.

Comment: If we move this discussion to chat, I could give you the link to the website

Comment: @bobjomes the chat is accessible by anyone if you are not allowed to share your site for security/privacy reasons, the chat won't make it a safer place. As I said your best option is trying to talk with someone nearby you and show your code